# Install jupiter with python 2.7

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I tried a lot of times to install a jupiter in anaconda with python 2.7
I did not succed, so I removed Anaconda and reinstalled everything.
Now following a tutorial in order to have the new environment I need to execute this commands in the CMD.exe:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7
conda activate py27
conda install notebook ipykernel
ipython kernel install --user
```

The third command failed with the following error:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(740): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::ipykernel-4.10.0-py27_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::ipykernel-4.10.0-py27_0
location of failed script: C:\Users\admin\anaconda3\envs\py27\Scripts\.ipykernel-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout:
stderr:
return code: 1

()
```

I tried to find the error on Internet, but I could not find the specific, in similar questions the answer was to disable the antivirus. I did, but nothing work.